# How to change source control binding of VS 2005 solution through C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version-control, automation, visual-sourcesafe

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2005. I need to change its source control binding from one branch in Visual SourceSafe to another through automation by C# code. I would like to know if there are any APIs to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To bind version controlled projects and solutions to Visual Studio

1. Highlight the project or solution you wish to bind to Team Foundation version control in Solution Explorer.
2. On the File menu, click Source Control, and then click Change Source Control.
3. In Change Source Control dialog box, click Bind.

To unbind version controlled projects and solutions to Visual Studio

1. Highlight the project or solution you wish to unbind in Team Foundation version control in Solution Explorer.
2. On the File menu, click Source Control, and then click Change Source Control.
3. In the Change Source Control dialog box, highlight the solution or project you wish to unbind from version control, and in the toolbar, click Unbind.

It does not seem that there are any official API's that can do this, however Saveen Reddy has uploaded a tool that I have not tested onto codeplex and says it works. Here is the link: [Saveen Reddy's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2012/08/11/a-tool-to-remove-source-control-bindings-from-visual-studio-solutions-and-projects.aspx)

I would like to find out if you used it how it went?